# how to resolve AFC_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR in iMobileDevice-Net

Tags: c#, iphone, itunes

I am trying to work with [imobiledevice-net](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net) and for a starting point have tested a few code samples that I found across the internet. So far so good. But when I try use [this](https://github.com/geiszla/iOSLib) library odd thing happens:
when I connect an old iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2 everything works fine, but when I connect a newer iPhone 7 with iOS 11.4.1 there is a problem in AFC.CS:

```
//DllImport   
[DllImport("libimobiledevice.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern AFCError afc_client_start_service(IntPtr deviceHandle, out IntPtr afcClient, string label);

//usage 
AFCError returnCode = afc_client_start_service(device.handle, out afcClient, "iOSLib");
```

the `returnCode` here is `1` or `AFC_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR`. How should I resolve this issue?

- I am using the latest version of iTunes on windows 10 x64.

Comment: There have been a lot of changes between iOS 7 and iOS 11. You may be using an old version of libimobiledevice that doesn't have the fixes to make it work with iOS 11. Why did you move from imobiledevice-net to iOSLib? imobiledevice-net has the AFC function you reference, and ships with (fairly) up to date versions of libimobiledevice.

Comment: @FrederikCarlier Thanks for the hint. I found afc api in imobiledevice-net and works fine. but out of curiosity which one do you think is more stable? using imobiledevice-net or using iTunesMobileDevice.dll directly?

Comment: I'm the maintainer of imobiledevice-net so I'm biased towards imobiledevice-net ;-).

Comment: @FrederikCarlier I know this is not a good place to ask a question. but I'm having problems (memory corrupt error) while using afc_file_read. where can I post my question? Is there a community?

Comment: Best is to open a question on StackOverflow, actually. You can optionally open an issue in the imobiledevice-net GitHub repository and link the StackOverflow question there. But remember - no guarantees; I don't provide SLAs for work that I do for free ;-).